# Error C2280: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a problem trying to create a VC++ Static Library that uses C++11 standard threads.

I currently have two classes, and I am able to declare and later define a thread just fine on my starting class (which is declared last). At this stage, the code is just a socket listener which then creates an object of another class to handle each client accepted. Those child objects are supposed to create the threads I need for parallel data capture, encoding and transmission.

The problem is: If I declare a std::thread on my other class, even if exactly like I did on my start class, no matter what, I'm getting this error on build `error C2280: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function   [...]\vc\include\functional 1124    1`

The only way I was able to workaround this error is to simply not declare a `std::thread` object in the latter class, which isn't possible, according to what I want it to do...

I'm using VS2013, and my sources are:

**stdafx.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

**StreamServer.h**

```
#pragma once
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 65535
#define DEFAULT_PORT "5649"

class StreamServerClient
{
public:
    bool* terminate;
    //std::thread client;     //If I comment this line out, it builds just fine.
    void DoNothing();
    StreamServerClient(SOCKET clientSock, bool* ptTerm);
    StreamServerClient();
    ~StreamServerClient();
};

class StreamServer
{
public:
    bool terminate;
    std::thread Listener;
    std::vector<StreamServerClient> clients;
    void CreateClient(SOCKET, bool*);
    void Listen();
    StreamServer();
    ~StreamServer();
};
```

**StreamServer.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StreamServer.h"

StreamServerClient::StreamServerClient(SOCKET clientSock, bool* ptTerm)
{
    terminate = ptTerm;
    //client = std::thread(&StreamServerClient::DoNothing, this);     //Same thing as the declaration
}

StreamServerClient::StreamServerClient()
{
    *terminate = false;
    //client = std::thread(&StreamServerClient::DoNothing, this);     //Same thing as the declaration
}

void StreamServerClient::DoNothing()
{
}

StreamServerClient::~StreamServerClient()
{
}

void StreamServer::Listen()
{
    {...}
    do {
        clients.push_back(StreamServerClient::StreamServerClient(accept(listenSock, NULL, NULL), &terminate));
        std::cout << "accepted a client!" << std::endl;
    } while (!terminate);
}

StreamServer::StreamServer()
{
    terminate = false;
    Listener = std::thread(&StreamServer::Listen, this);
    Listener.detach();
}

StreamServer::~StreamServer()
{
}
```

Comment: `std::thread`s cannot be copied. Aka, the copy constructor is `deleted`.

Comment: @remyabel But then why am I able to do it just fine for StreamServer? What am I missing here?

Comment: @remyabel Crap, think I just noticed what happens... It also disappears if I comment out the `clients.push_back(...)`. Should I use a `std::thread *` instead, then?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Objects of type `std::thread` can't be copied. You are best off to just initialize the objects in the member initializer list:

```
class StreamServerClient
{
public:
    bool* terminate;
    std::thread client;
    void DoNothing();
    StreamServerClient(SOCKET clientSock, bool* ptTerm);
    StreamServerClient(StreamServerClient&& other);
    ~StreamServerClient();
};

StreamServerClient::StreamServerClient(SOCKET clientSock, bool* ptTerm)
    : terminate(ptTerm)
    , client(std::thread(&StreamServerClient::DoNothing, this)) {
}
StreamServerClient::StreamServerClient(StreamServerClient&& other)
    : terminate(other.terminate)
    , client(std::move(other.client)) {
}
```

I ommitted the default constructor (note that your version doesn't work because it tries to assign a value to the result of dereferencing an uninitialized pointer) and instead added a move constructor: when pushing back to the `std::vector<...>` this constructor will be called when providing something which looks like a temporary (i.e., something which either *is* a temporary or is made to look like one, e.g., using `std::move()`).

Comment: I'm really confused about what the member initializer list has to do with anything.  How is this different from doing initialization in the constructor, in this case?

Comment: @Andrey: Initializer lists initialize. Assignments assign. Different methods.

Comment: @Andrey: you could initialize things in the body as well but it would amount to first default constructing the object and then [move] assigning to it. There is no need to do so. Admittidly, I have also missed the `push_back()` when I first read the question.

Answer (score 8):

An `std::thread` object is not copyable.  When this line is called:

```
clients.push_back(StreamServerClient::StreamServerClient(accept(listenSock, NULL, NULL), &terminate));
```

The `StreamServerClient` object you create needs to be added to the `clients` vector, but the only way to do that is by copying it because your `StreamServer` object does not have a move constructor defined.  The default copy constructor for `StreamServerClient` is generated, and what the default copy constructor in C++11 does is, it calls the copy constructors of all of the data members.

In this case it is calling the copy constructor of the `std::thread` data member, which is deleted.

The reason `std::thread`s can't be copied is that a `std::thread` object corresponds to a thread of execution.  You should refactor your code, IMO.  You could hack together a move constructor for `StreamServerClient`, but I think there are cleaner solutions, for example, replacing the `std::thread` with a pointer to `std::thread` and initializing the thread with a completely separate call.

**Edit:** In general I would say it is unwise to branch a new thread in an object's contructor, because it is too delicate an operation.  (It can fail, then you have to deal with exceptions, etc.)  Although probably C++ purists will disagree with me.

**Edit:** Had stupid terminology.

Comment: "a move copy constructor" wat