# C++ objects and threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, object, vector

I am doing a simple server apllication, where you can have multiple connections, each connection is a single thread. This is the example I would like it to look like(it doesn't work), there is a collection of threads where each thread instantiates an object of the class connection:

```
class connection{};

class server{
std::vector<std::thread> active_connections;
public:
    void listen() {active_connections.push_back(std::thread(connection));}
};
```

I have been searching for the solution, but the best I could find were some member function threads. The solution turned quite wrong when I tested it, for example:

```
class connection{};

class server{
std::vector<std::thread> active_connections;
public:
    void new_connection() { ... }
    void listen() { 
        active_connections.push_back(std::thread(&server::new_connection,this)); }
    };
```

The message was: error: use of deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(const std::thread&).
Does that mean the std::thread class wants to copy the server class?? I don't know C++ that much so please don't flame, I'm only asking.

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is where this happens:

```
void server::do_listen()
{   
    int addr_size = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
    sockaddr_in client_sock;
    connection_info cn_info;

    while(true)
    {
        int csock;
        if((csock = accept(server_sock, (sockaddr*)&client_sock, (socklen_t*)&addr_size)) != -1)
        {
            printf("Incomming connection from %s.\n", inet_ntoa(client_sock.sin_addr));
            memset(&cn_info,0, sizeof(connection_info));
            cn_info.sock_addr = client_sock;
            cn_info.sock = csock;
            std::thread thr(&server::new_connection, *this, cn_info);
            thr.join();
        }

    }
}
```

This is by far. The `server::new_connection()` is still empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error C2280: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723566/error-c2280-stdthreadthreadconst-stdthread-attempting-to-referenc)

Comment: It means that something is trying to copy a `thread` object, which isn't copyable. But the code you've posted doesn't do that, and compiles once I fix the obvious error (`active_connections` should be a variable, not a function). Please post a minimal test case that demonstrates the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
std::thread thr(&server::new_connection, *this, cn_info);
                                         ^
```

You're binding a *copy* of the server object; which isn't copyable because it contains (a container of) non-copyable `thread` objects. Instead, bind a pointer:

```
std::thread thr(&server::new_connection, this, cn_info);
```

Some might find a lambda more readable; this captures the `this` pointer and `cn_info` by value:

```
std::thread thr([=]{new_connection(cn_info);});
```

As a commentor mentions, you could obfuscate the solution by binding a [reference wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
std::thread thr(&server::new_connection, std::ref(*this), cn_info);
```

but I prefer to remove, rather than add, complexity where possible.

Comment: +1 but let's also mention `std::ref` and `std::cref` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref

Comment: @Peter: If you say so. It's only peripherally related to this problem, and not needed here unless you've got a fetish for unnecessary complexity, but I've mentioned it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Does that mean the std::thread class wants to copy the server class?

No, that means a copy of a `std::thread` is made somewhere, but that's forbidden as `std::thread` in [NonCopyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) (note the `thread(const thread&) = delete;` in the list of constructors).

You should eliminate any code that performs a copy of a `thread`. The one you've posted doesn't perform such copy.

An example where a copy is made "behind the scene" would be a `push_back` in a vector of a thread variable, i.e.:

```
std::thread myThread;
myVector.push_back(myThread);
```

In your code:

```
active_connections.push_back(std::thread(&server::new_connection,this));
```

as you're pushing back a temporary, it doesn't get copied but moved into the vector.

Comment: Alright, this is not worded correctly. I meant the `push_back` op made (`push_back(std::thread(&server::new_connection,this));`) didn't copy. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

More a design question to you author:

You create one thread for one connection. If you have ten connections you have ten threads. But what do you do if you have 10000 connections you want to handle? I'm not sure your operating system likes that.

A much better connection handling approach - only in my opinion - would be if you only have N threads that handle your network connections. If your computer has e.g. six cores you could spend one, two or more threads only for the network stuff. So you have a thread pool of a certain size for this.

The proactor pattern could be interesting for you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proactor_pattern

If you're looking for a library that could handle such things, you could look to the upcoming C++ Boost library named Boost.Asynchronous:

https://github.com/henry-ch/asynchronous

This library is still in development, but really good. I've made some simple client/server applications with the library.

Comment: Or he could use the existing boost library asio: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Comment: Sure, Boost.Asio is available at the moment. But Boost.Asio has some nasty bugs. Writing a server handling multiple connections with Boost.Asio is not a funny thing ;-)